# If $\sigma=a-e^{1-b\epsilon}$ and $\frac{d\sigma}{d\epsilon}=\sigma$, find $\epsilon$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> So for this problem, I was given that $$\sigma = a - e^{1-b\epsilon}$$
>   and $${d\sigma\over d\epsilon}=\sigma$$
>
> I'm tasked with finding $\epsilon$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

This is what I've done so far:

Set the equations equal to each other and take the integral. 
$${d\sigma\over d\epsilon}=a - e^{1-b\epsilon}$$ 
$$\int d\sigma=\int(a-e^{1-b\epsilon})d\epsilon$$
 $$\sigma=a\epsilon+\frac 1 b e^{1-b\epsilon}$$

From here, I set the first given equation and the most recent equation equal to each other in an attempt to get rid of the $\sigma$.
$$a - e^{1-b\epsilon}=a\epsilon+\frac 1 b e^{1-b\epsilon}$$
To try to simplify this and get $\epsilon$ by itself, I tried to rearrange the equation.
$$a(1-\epsilon)=(1+\frac 1 b)e^{1-b\epsilon}$$
$$\epsilon=1-(1+\frac 1 b)\frac 1 a e^{1-b\epsilon}$$
Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to get past the fact that there is an $\epsilon$ in the exponential that is difficult to reconcile with the $\epsilon$ I've put on the left of the last equation. Thanks for your help, guys.

Comment: Why is this tagged algebra-precalculus, when it clearly involves calculus?

Comment: Anyway, I'd start by going from $d\sigma/d\epsilon=\sigma$ to $\sigma=Ce^{\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this method:

$$\sigma = a- e^{1-b\epsilon}$$

Differentiate this equation with respect to $\epsilon$

$$\frac{d\sigma}{d\epsilon}=be^{1-b\epsilon}$$

$$e^{1-b\epsilon}= \frac{1}{b} \frac{d\sigma}{d\epsilon}= \frac{\sigma}{b}............(A)$$

Put this value of $e^{1-b\epsilon}$ in the  first equation

$$\sigma = a - \frac{\sigma}{b}$$

$$\sigma = \frac{ab}{b+1}$$

Now substitute this value of $\sigma$ in (A)

$$e^{1-b\epsilon} = \frac{a}{b+1}$$

Take natural logarithm on both sides

$$1-b\epsilon = log_e(\frac{a}{b+1})$$

**$$\epsilon = \frac{1-log(\frac{a}{b+1})}{b}$$**

Hope this helps...........:-)